# Prove that either $g$ is constant or $f\equiv 0$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ entire, $D$ a open and connected, $g:D\to \Bbb C$ is analytic with $f(g(z))=0$ for all $z$ in $\Bbb D$. Proof that $g$ is constant or $f≡0$. Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 3):

$f(g(z))=0$ for every $x\in D$. Then $(f(g(z)))'=f'(g(z))\cdot g'(z)=0$ for every $z\in D$. Suppose that $g$ is not constant ,then because $D$ is a domain(open and connected) we have that $g'(z)\neq 0$ for every $z\in D$ and hence $f'(g(z))=0$ for every $z\in D$. This means (also becasue $D$ is a domain) that $f$ is constant in $D$ (from the identity theorem) and $f(g(z))=0=>f=0$.

Comment: @Roos Jansen ,check my proof please.thank you